# prerendring issue when i make the nex.js 13 build both nexjs and django are on the docker

Tags: docker, next.js, docker-compose, server-side-rendering, next.js13

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  backend:
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: backend/Dockerfile
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/code/backend
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    networks:
      - mynetwork
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: prod.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - backend  
    networks:
      - mynetwork    

networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

This is my docker-compose file for frontend and backend

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS base
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY  package.json  package-lock.json* ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
ARG BASE_URL
ENV BASE_URL=http://localhost:8000
ARG NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL=http://localhost:8000
RUN npm run lint:fix
RUN npm run fmt:fix
RUN npm run build
CMD [ "npm","start" ]
```

This is my docker file for frontned

```
FROM python:3.10.4

# set work directory
WORKDIR /code

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install dependencies
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y postgresql-client
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# copy project
COPY ./backend /code/backend

# change directory to backend
WORKDIR /code/backend

# install project dependencies
COPY ./backend/requirements.txt /code/backend/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./backend/docker-entrypoint.sh /code/backend/docker-entrypoint.sh
# make the entrypoint script executable
RUN chmod +x /code/backend/docker-entrypoint.sh

# set the user
USER root

ENTRYPOINT ["/code/backend/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

This is my docker file for backend

Now when i am running the docker-compose it gave me the issue in build

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEqxE.png)

I think it will try to fetch the data in build time i am using ssr for the api calls

-this is key highlight that i am using ssr to fetch the apis from django server.

but it do not able to fetch the data because on build time backend is not up

i also try to up the backend image and frontend image seprately first i up backend and then backend but same issue is occuring

for dev mode it works fine for http://backend:8000

in prod mode i try with docker ip , localhst and backend but nothing works i dont know what is happening...